# Display an image before page finished loading

Tags: javascript, html, image, asynchronous

I have a mobile website with some contents and an image.

The image was initially set to [display:none]. After it is fully loaded, it changes to [display:block]. Below shows what have I done:

```
// Other website codes................

<div id='creative_div' style="display:none; width:100%;">
<img id='banner' src='http://www.example.com/my_image.jpg' style="width:100%;">
</div>

<script> 
window.onload=function(){
if (document.getElementById("banner").complete && document.getElementById("banner").naturalWidth != 0){
loadImage();
}
if (!document.getElementById("banner").complete || document.getElementById("banner").naturalWidth == 0){
hide('creative_div');
}
}
</script>

<script>
function loadImage() {
document.getElementById("creative_div").style.display="block";
}
</script>

// Other website codes............
```

So in this case, the image will started to load when the page is loading, and it will be displayed once the page finished loading.

However, I would like the image to show once it is loaded, no matter the website is fully loaded or not. I've searched about this issue, but it seems Javascript have to execute after the page is fully loaded. I've also found something about "async" which is used for Javascript, so I really have no idea how it works.......

Any suggestions? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what problem you are trying to solve, but you can attach an onload handler to the image object itself and then when the image loads, it can make itself visible without regard to the load state of the rest of the page (e.g. even if the rest of the page is still loading).

```
<img id='banner' onload='showme(this)' src='http://www.example.com/my_image.jpg'
 style="width:100%; display: none;">

function showme(obj) {
    obj.style.display = "block";
}
```

Or, if you want to make the parent container visible, then it could be this:

```
<img id='banner' onload='showme(this)' src='http://www.example.com/my_image.jpg'
 style="width:100%;">

function showme(obj) {
    obj.parentNode.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to mess js(onload handler) with html. Better way is to attach handler outsite html for all images, and then handle style change.

Comment: @KarolSikora - if you want the load handler to fire BEFORE the page's javascript has been loaded and to fire immediately if the image loads immediately from the browser cache, then you CAN'T install the event handler later via javascript - if the image is specified in the HTML, you HAVE to also install the event handler in the HTML.  This is the only way that guarantees that the load handler is installed when the image finishes loading.  This is one case where the event handlers needs to be in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick can be to show image on first page. Then load original page from that page. :)
This way the image will show as soon as it gets loaded. Then on first page's onload event u can call second page code :/